# makefile is giving me collect2: error: 1d returned 1 exit status amoung other things

Tags: c++, c, unix, makefile

Hi i am new to stackoverflow and kinda new programming as well anyway my problem is with the makefile
here the contents of the makefile that i have

```
m3b.o: myDefs.h m3b. 
   g++ -c m3b.c -o m3b.o


m3a.o:       m3a.c  
    g++ -c m3a.c -o m3a.o

m3.o:        m3.c
    g++ -c m3.c -o m3.o

m2.o:       myDefs.h m2.c   
    g++ -c m2.c -o m2.o 

m1.o:       m1.c
    g++ -c m1.c -o m1.o 

main.exe:   main.c m1.o m2.o m3.o m3a.o m3b.o
    g++ main.c m1.o m2.o m3.o m3a.o m3b.o  -o main.exe***
```

Sorry for the setup i just copied and paste and it turned out like that.

the error i  get is undefined reference to "main"
collect2: error: 1d returned 1 exit status
makefile:17: recipe for target 'main.exe' failed
make **[make.exe] Error1

things i tried: i went online and read that makefile can sometimes be tricky with the spaces and tabs so i changed those. i also the changed the gcc to g++, i changed m3.o to take in m3a.o and m3b.o but couldnt compile because of a linker issue. so i put it where it is now and i have no idea what else to do.

Comment: Please clean (remove) all object files and the `main.exe` file (if it exists), then run `make` again. Now please [edit] your question and copy-paste (as text!) the *full* and *complete* output into the question. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As a hint though: Have you defined (implemented) a global [`main` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) in your code? In which source file?